# Upload files after connection is restored

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, blueimp

I'm new in the usage of [BlueImp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and I was looking for a way to upload a video after the connection is restored.

Is there a way to Upload a video with this requirements?

Comment: Anybody ? Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: Searched the web and haventfound any working solution. Anybody ?

Comment: I made an edit (waiting for review atm) that will make things easier to understand. But sorry I'm not familiar with BlueImp

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot upload from an iPhone to a website. There's no open file system on the iPhone. You'd have to create a native app that has the capabilities to access the camera roll and upload to server from there.

Comment: You can in iOS 6 http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/13/ios-6-safari-media-uploads/

Comment: swatkins - Sorry should explain that there will be an app whith capabilities to access the camera roll and upload to server.

Comment: Michel Ayres - Thank you for the edit. I will learn how to write better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blueimp Wiki has documentation on how to handle resuming. Please see the following documentation:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

> Note: Chunked file uploads are only supported by browsers with support
>   for XHR file uploads and the Blob API, which includes Google Chrome
>   and Mozilla Firefox 4+.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed Thank you. I search'd and search'd but couldn't find it. Thank you.